# AJAX request with Jquery without page refresh, using both options object and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am attempting to validate and post form data, using the Jquery form plugin, as well as validate (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm).

I have tried sending data without validation, and it works fine.  For example:

```
$('#encodeForm').ajaxForm(function(res) {
    $('#result').html(res.data);
    console.log(res);
    return false;
});
```

The `return false` prevents the page from navigating to the server response.

However, the above fails to work when I substitute an options object for the function:

```
$('#encodeForm').ajaxForm({ ......, success : function() { return false; } });
```

With respect to passing the options object, how is it possible to prevent page navigation (AJAX response instead?)

**Methods attempted:**

1. Nesting form within validation callback (current)
2. Nesting validation within form callback (failed)
3. Using form.submit closure over form (failed)

Comment: In the [example](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) you posted, they aren't calling `return false` anywhere. Are you sure that's necessary? Compare your code to the code in the example I linked.

Comment: I've removed the tag [tag:jquery-validate] from your question because I see absolutely nothing in the OP about this plugin.  If I'm wrong, then where is your `.validate()` code?

Comment: @Abraham Yes, that worked.  I don't think this deserves a downvote - 2 implementations from the modules were used, and were pretty similar to each other.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky No, It is with regard to the jquery-validate plugin as well.  I am using 2 of them.

Comment: Does anybody knows the browsser support for Jquery Form plugin?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#encodeForm').submit(function() {
    // submit the form
    $(this).ajaxSubmit();
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, however it does not appear to send the file payload.  What worked for me was to use ajaxform() instead, and have the validate() separately.

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around with the code, and Abraham's note, the following worked for me:

```
        $('#decodeForm').validate({
            // rules here ....


            }
        });


    $('#decodeForm').ajaxForm({

        beforeSubmit : function() {

            console.log('FORM: ' + $('#decodeForm').valid());

            //block if false
            return $('#decodeForm').valid();

        },

        success : function(res) {
            if (res.err) {
                console.log('ERROR: ' + res.err);

            }
            // do something with the data

        }

    });
```

**Note:** It appears that the AJAX query will not work if the rules are invalid.  Ensure that the `additional-methods.min.js` file is included, if you are using functions from there.